# Непонятные байты между хидерами и боди

Tags: node.js, http

**Алгоритм роботы:**

1. На node js сервере получаю от клиента запрос по http протоколу;
2. По веб сокету перенаправляю его на Qt'ешный сервер на обработку;
3. От Qt'ешного сервера, получаю ответ по веб сокету и отправляю его клиенту по http протоколу

   ```
   response.write(message.binaryData);
   response.end();
   ```

**Проблема**

Принимающая сторона жалуется на наличие в разделителе между хидерами и боди непонятного плавающего количества байт (три либо четыре). Они ожидают что между заголовками и телом будет два переноса строки

```
0d 0a 0d 0a
```

а по факту приходит два переноса плюс один или два байта плюс перенос а потом только body

```
0d 0a 0d 0a 63 0d 0a
```

Помогите разобраться что это такое.

ps: байты добавляются только при наличии body

pss: [HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/httprequester/) все нормально парсит, делаю предположение что у меня все ок, но я ничего не смог найти в стандартах про эти байты

Comment: Очень похоже на самый обычный мусор. Нужно как минимум смотреть, как там отправляются данные на qt стороне.

Comment: Насколько я помню HTTP, разделителем в нём является `0d0a0d0a`, сразу после него начинается тело. Эти "лишние байты" это часть тела.

Comment: @KoVadim дело в том что я для теста выпилил qt сторону вообще. на запрос клиента просто отправляю средствами ноды следующее `response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});response.write("404 Not Found");response.end();` и получаю между заголовками и "404 Not Found" не `0d 0a 0d 0a` а `0d 0a 0d 0a 64 0d 0a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По умолчанию, Node.js использует [chunked transfer encoding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), случайные байты совсем не случайны, а являются размером следующего за ними блока. Формат примерно такой:

```
…              // протокол и заголовки;
0d 0a 0d 0a    // конец заголовков, дальше — тело;
63 0d 0a       // размер куска — 12 байт, разделитель;
…  0d 0a       // кусок размером 12 байт, разделитель;
…              // возможно, ещё куски;
0 0d 0a 0d 0a  // конец.
```

Каждый [`res.write()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) передаёт размер chunk'а и сам chunk. [`res.end()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) пишет последний chunk, если его передать, и метку завершения chunk'ов (`0\r\n\r\n`).

Правильным решением, на мой взгляд, будет добавить поддержку chunked encoding в "принимающую сторону". Если это невозможно или нетривиально, в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729329/node-js-disable-chunked-transfer-encoding) есть пример кода, отключающий такое поведение и позволяющий отправить запрос целиком и сразу.

Comment: @D-side похоже на правду, спасибо! Не стесняйся предлагать правки к ответам :)

Comment: Боюсь, я не могу **предлагать** правки. У меня репы столько, что мои правки принимаются без вопросов .-. Поэтому я этого и избегаю.

Comment: @D-side Ну так это ведь не зря!

Comment: @elmigranto спасибо